# docker-entrypoint-initdb.d is empty when container is started from within another container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have a directory structure like -

```
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- db
  - schema.sql
```

and contents of each file is -

**Dockerfile** -

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache docker python3 && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .docker-compose-deps python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make && \
    pip3 install docker-compose && \
    apk del .docker-compose-deps

ADD . .
```

**docker-compose.yml** -

```
version: "2"

services:

  test_mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    container_name: test_mysql_v1
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "3310:3306"
```

**schema.sql** -

```
create database if not exists db2;
```

When I do -

```
docker-compose up --build --remove-orphans
```

it behaves expectedly and I get a db called *db2* inside *test_mysql_v1* container.

However, when I do -

```
1. docker build -t dfd_1 .

2. docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it dfd_1 sh

from inside -

3. docker-compose up  --build --remove-orphans
```

Then in newly created *test_mysql_v1* container, *docker-entrypoint-initdb.d* directory is empty (no db created).

Can someone please help how to make this work?

End result should be - when I run *docker-compose up* from inside *dfd_1* container, it should create a mysql container with **db already created**.

Additional notes -

1. To bring down mysql container, I use - `docker-compose down`
2. My guess is when I do `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...`, then I require another volume mount so that *docker-compose.yml* (inside *dfd_1*) can copy *db* to *docker-entrypoint-initdb.d* correctly.
3. Got nothing from docker logs.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved it by passing path on host directory to the container within.

Changed **docker run** command as -

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e HOST_DIR=$PWD -it dfd_1 sh
```

And **docker-compose.yml** (used *HOST_DIR* env variable while mapping volume) as -

```
version: "2"

services:

  test_mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    container_name: test_mysql_v1
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_DIR}/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "3310:3306"
```